# Preventing cursorPosition change when converting numeric number to scientific notation in SwiftUI TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have implemented a SwiftUI TextField that accepts numeric input and allows users to perform calculations. When the number entered is too large or too small, I convert it to scientific notation using MyTextField. However, I noticed that when the number is converted to scientific notation, the cursorPosition in the TextField changes as well. This is causing issues with the user experience as the cursorPosition is not consistent with the user's input.

Function to get cursorPosition:

```
func insertNumber(_ number: String) {
        print("cursorPosition: ", cursorPosition)
        print("displayValue: ", displayValue.startIndex)

        // If not in scientific notation
        if displayValue.count > 0 {
            // Check if cursorPosition is within the bounds of the string
            if cursorPosition > displayValue.count {
                cursorPosition = displayValue.count
            }
            let index = displayValue.index(displayValue.startIndex, offsetBy: cursorPosition)
            displayValue.insert(contentsOf: number, at: index)
        } else {
            displayValue = number
        }

        cursorPosition = min(cursorPosition + number.count, 15)
        lastEnteredCharacter = displayValue.last
        print(cursorPosition)
    }
```

Struct MyTextField

```
struct MyTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var currentText: String
    @Binding var cursorPosition: Int // Track the cursor position
    @Binding var updateView: Bool
    @Binding var isInScientificNotation: Bool
    
    var placeHolder: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.inputView = UIView() // hiding keyboard
        textField.inputAccessoryView = UIView() // hiding keyboard toolbar
        textField.placeholder = placeHolder
        textField.textColor = UIColor.red
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator

        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 104)
        textField.textAlignment = .right // Right-align text

        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textField: UITextField, context: Context) {
        // Only update the text field's text if it's different from SwiftUI view's currentText
        if textField.text != self.currentText {
               textField.text = self.currentText
        }

        // Check the cursor position is within the text length
        if cursorPosition > textField.text?.count ?? 0 {
            cursorPosition = textField.text?.count ?? 0
        }

        // Set the cursor position
        if let newPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: cursorPosition) {
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        }

        // Check if the number is too large or too small for the display
        let numberString = "\(currentText)"
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.locale = .current
        formatter.roundingMode = .down

        if let number = Double(numberString), (abs(number) > 99999999999999 || (number != 0 && abs(number) < 0.000001)) || isInScientificNotation {
               // Use exponential notation for very large or very small numbers, or if the number is already in scientific notation
               formatter.numberStyle = .scientific
               textField.text = formatter.string(for: number)
               textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 44) // Use a fixed font size for exponential notation
               self.cursorPosition = textField.text?.count ?? 0 // Move cursor to the end
        } else {
            // Adjust font size to prevent text from going out of border
            let maxFontSize: CGFloat = 44 // Set the maximum font size
            var currentFontSize = maxFontSize

            while let currentText = textField.text {
                let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: currentFontSize)]
                let textSize = currentText.size(withAttributes: attributes)
                if textSize.width <= textField.bounds.width && textSize.height <= textField.bounds.height {
                    break
                }

                currentFontSize -= 1
                if currentFontSize < 0 { // Set a minimum font size
                    break
                }
            }

            textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: currentFontSize)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: MyTextField

        init(parent: MyTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
                       let cursorPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.endOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
                       self.parent.cursorPosition = textField.text?.count ?? 0 - cursorPosition
                   }
               }
           }

        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if let currentValue = textField.text {
                // Calculate the resulting string after replacement
                if let swiftRange = Range(range, in: currentValue) {
                    let updatedValue = currentValue.replacingCharacters(in: swiftRange, with: string)

                    // Check if the resulting text length exceeds the maximum allowed length
                    let maxLength = 15
                    if updatedValue.count > maxLength {
                        // If the new value exceeds the limit, don't allow the replacement
                        return false
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parent.currentText = updatedValue
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried setting the cursorPosition explicitly to a fixed value, but it still changes after the conversion. I am looking for insights or alternative approaches to maintain the cursorPosition at the same location after the number conversion.

example: after adding 1's 15 times it shows "1.1E14". Then after, if I press the "+" symbol, it should have to add at the end but the "+" is adding at the middle due to this line:

```
cursorPosition = displayValue.count
```

But I want to add this at the end.